# Specific Page/Post Need to Stay Non SSL

Tags: security, ssl, https, http

I have a website that is already SSL secured. I want to have a plugin that will give me a tick mark option to make the page/post as non-SSL.  Rarely I need to use that but that is not a small amount, must be hundreds of pages/posts need to do this. That's why I need a permanent and stable solution for this.

Which plugin will give me that option? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. This plugin gives the option of set SSL on or off based on post or page https://really-simple-ssl.com/downloads/really-simple-ssl-per-page/